# if else condition on Assert.assertEquals selenium testNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am working on selenium and testNG with java.. I have some problem about this code:

```
Assert.assertEquals(webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), "http://google.com");
```

the question is how to create if else condition in assertEquals. like this

```
if( Assert.assertEquals(webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), "http://google.com"));
{
    //do Nothing
}

else
{
   // take screenshoot
}
```

any idea guys?

Comment: Use an `if` without an `assert`.

Comment: and assert method doesn't return anything so you can't write in if condition.

Answer (score 7):

If an assert fails, it throws an assertionError.  You need to catch the AssertionError and in the catch capture the screenshot.

```
try{
   Assert.assertEquals(...,...);
}catch(AssertionError e){
   Log error;
   Takescreenshot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = webDriver.getCurrentUrl();
if(url == "http://google.com")
{
    // take screenshoot
}

Assert.assertEquals(url, "http://google.com")
```

Comment: You shouldn't test `String` equality with `==` (that only tests reference identity). Also, it's `String` (not `string`).

Answer (score 0):

If the condition in `Assert.assertEquals()` is false, for example `Assert.assertEquals("qwerty", "asdfgh")`, the test will terminate, so there is no point to put it in `if` statement.

If you want the test to to take screenshot in failure you can write your on `assertEquals` implementation

```
public static class Assert
{
    public static void assertEquals(Object actualResult, Object expectedResult, boolean stopOnError = true)
    {
        if (!expectedResult.equals(actualResult))
        {
            // take screenshot
            if (stopOnError)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then simply do

```
Assert.assertEquals(webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), "http://google.com"));
```

You can also change `stopOnError` to false to prevent test termination when they are not equal.

If you don't want the test to end if the URL is wrong simply do

```
if (!webDriver.getCurrentUrl().equals("http://google.com"))
{
    // take screenshot
}
```