# How to add SAS for file services of azure in java?

Tags: java, azure

I got code in c# or code for blob storage. I need some reference code in java to have SAS token for file storage in azure. The SAS may be applicable for account or services.

Code 1 :

```
static string GetAccountSASToken()
{
    // To create the account SAS, you need to use your shared key credentials. Modify for your account.
    const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

    // Create a new access policy for the account.
    SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List,
            Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob | SharedAccessAccountServices.File,
            ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
        };

    // Return the SAS token.
    return storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
}
```

This code is about creating SAS token for account verification and expiry time.I need the same in java. I am not getting few things like, in first code how I can write the 'Permission' in java? I mean multiple in one line. Please provide equivalent java code for this.

Code 2 :

```
@Test
    public String testFileSAS(CloudFileShare share, CloudFile file) throws InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalArgumentException, StorageException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        SharedAccessFilePolicy policy = createSharedAccessPolicy(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessFilePermissions.READ,
                SharedAccessFilePermissions.LIST, SharedAccessFilePermissions.WRITE), 24);
        FileSharePermissions perms = new FileSharePermissions();
        // SharedAccessProtocols protocol = SharedAccessProtocols.HTTPS_ONLY;
        perms.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("readperm", policy);

        share.uploadPermissions(perms);
        // Thread.sleep(30000);

        CloudFile sasFile = new CloudFile(
                new URI(file.getUri().toString() + "?" + file.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm")));
        sasFile.download(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

        // do not give the client and check that the new file's client has the
        // correct permissions
        CloudFile fileFromUri = new CloudFile(
                PathUtility.addToQuery(file.getStorageUri(), file.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm")));
        assertEquals(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.class.toString(),
                fileFromUri.getServiceClient().getCredentials().getClass().toString());

        // create credentials from sas
        StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(
                file.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy, null, null));
        System.out.println("Generated SAS token is : " + file.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy, null, null));
        String token = file.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy, null, null);
        CloudFileClient client = new CloudFileClient(sasFile.getServiceClient().getStorageUri(), creds);

        CloudFile fileFromClient = client.getShareReference(file.getShare().getName()).getRootDirectoryReference()
                .getFileReference(file.getName());
        assertEquals(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.class.toString(),
                fileFromClient.getServiceClient().getCredentials().getClass().toString());
        assertEquals(client, fileFromClient.getServiceClient());
        // self written
        // String sharedUri =
        // file.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy,null,null);
        // System.out.println("token created is : "+sharedUri);
        return token;
    }

    private final static SharedAccessFilePolicy createSharedAccessPolicy(EnumSet<SharedAccessFilePermissions> sap,
            int expireTimeInSeconds) {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, expireTimeInSeconds);
        SharedAccessFilePolicy policy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy();
        policy.setPermissions(sap);
        policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());
        return policy;
    }
```

This code is a jUnit test. I don' want to import jUnit library. Want to do it in pure java.How I can convert the code? What I can use instead of assertEqauls?

Comment: Can you provide us additional information, what Java version you are running on, what you have tried so far, where you will run the code? This platform is not supposed to provide final code to you, it shall be used to increase a knowledge base for solving problems on your own.

Comment: Sure. I have added c# code which I want to use in java. Please see the updated question.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consider the following code snippet in Java.

```
public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";

public String getAccountSASToken() throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException {

    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

    SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy();
    policy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessAccountPermissions.READ, SharedAccessAccountPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessAccountPermissions.LIST));
    policy.setServices(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessAccountService.BLOB, SharedAccessAccountService.FILE) );
    policy.setResourceTypes(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessAccountResourceType.SERVICE));
    policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plusHours(24L).toInstant()));
    policy.setProtocols(SharedAccessProtocols.HTTPS_ONLY);

    return account.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy);
}
```

Comment: Exactly on the point what was required.Thanks. Please see the edited question, I have added code2 which is jUnit test and want to convert in java. I am searching for alternative of 'assertEquals' of jUnit in java. Can you please help to reconstruct this code in pure java rather than jUnit? I am using jdk 1.8. Thank you.

Comment: You can just remove `assertEquals` if you don't want to test it. Or use `if` statement instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891265/if-else-condition-on-assert-assertequals-selenium-testng/34891312#34891312

Comment: Thanks.Link is helpful.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at this question :  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450473/how-to-download-file-having-spaces-in-its-name-from-azure-by-java-service